# Animate value with how far you scrolled in PageView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

so I was wondering if it is possible to animate a value scrolling to the next page. But not just onPageChanged but also in between. So for example like in snapchat where the top elements(search bar etc.) fade away with the opacity depending on how close you are to the next page (or how far you are from the current).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to work with `PageView` or `PageView.Builder` you can aim such effects if you control the pages with `PageController()` class. Then you can basically apply Transition effects and control navigating to next page with `GestureDetector` and functions, or with the given physics: parameter.

```
PageView.builder(
  controller: controller,
  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
    if (position == currentPageValue.floor()) {
      return Transform(
        transform: Matrix4.identity()..rotateX(currentPageValue - position),
        child: Container(
          color: position % 2 == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.pink,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              "Page",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else if (position == currentPageValue.floor() + 1){
      return Transform(
        transform: Matrix4.identity()..rotateX(currentPageValue - position),
        child: Container(
          color: position % 2 == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.pink,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              "Page",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Container(
        color: position % 2 == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.pink,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Page",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  },
  itemCount: 10,
)
```

You can check this article for getting such reseults:
https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-pageview-in-flutter-with-custom-transitions-581d9ea6dded

Comment: Thank you fot your answer! For me the controller.addListener with setState and then changing the value with the controller.page did it!